# Namedtuple and tuple comparison difference between python2.7 and python3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

This code works with python 3.5 but not with 2.7.

I'm trying to match a namedtuple by using a regular tuple containing the `mock.ANY` special object.

```
try:
    import unittest.mock as mock # python 3.5
except:
    import mock # python 2.7

def test_datetime():
    from collections import namedtuple
    from datetime import datetime
    A = namedtuple("A", ["a", "b"])
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    def foo(a):
        a.bar(A(now, "b"))
    a = mock.MagicMock()
    foo(a)
    a.bar.assert_called_once_with((mock.ANY, "b"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Testing")
    test_datetime()
```

How can I make it work in python 2.7 as well?
What's the reason for that?

**I can't change interpreter version**

**EDIT**:

Further reduced to

```
try:
    import unittest.mock as mock # python 3.5
except:
    import mock # python 2.7
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
A = namedtuple("A", ["a"])
(mock.ANY,)==A(now) # False in py2.7, true in py3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason mock is seeing tuples and namedtuples as different objects. The following code passes for me in python 2.7

```
>>> def test_datetime():
...     from collections import namedtuple
...     from datetime import datetime
...     A = namedtuple("A", ["a", "b"])
...     now = datetime.utcnow()
...     def foo(a):
...         a.bar(A(now, "b"))
...     a = mock.MagicMock()
...     foo(a)
...     a.bar.assert_called_once_with(A(mock.ANY, "b"))
```